# .htaccess RewriteRules don't work

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a little problem. I am trying to set up my website and everything is working fine but I have issues with the <kbd>.htaccess</kbd> file.

I want to remove the `.html` endings and the `pages/` part from the url when accessing a file from the pages folder

Example:

**This**: `http://example.com/pages/name.html` **to** `http://example.com/name`

This is the code i'm using right now:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\$ \$1.html

RewriteRule ^pages/(.+)\.html /$1.html [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+pages/(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ pages/$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, I was sleeping. I'll try it out in a minute.